# jQueryValidate - Required field - depends doesn't work

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

With jQueryValidate, I'm trying to make a field required only if another specific field is empty. So, after searching on the Internet, I did this :

```
rules: {
     marque: {
          required: {
               depends: function() {
                    if (($('#add_marque').val() == "Ajouter une marque" && $('#marque').val() == -1) || ($('#add_marque').val() == "" && $('#marque').val() == -1)) {
                         return true;
                     }
                     else {
                         return false;
                     }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. But, if I do this :

```
depends: function() {
     if (($('#add_marque').val() == "Ajouter une marque" && $('#marque').val() == -1) || ($('#add_marque').val() == "" && $('#marque').val() == -1)) {
          alert("Here!");
          return true;
      }
      else {
           return false;
      }
}
```

The alert box appears. So, my test seems to work.
Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?
I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 and qTip2 with jQueryValidate.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax and use of the plugin is correct from what you have given.  You need to troubleshoot, so first try this

```
marque: {
    required: true;
}
```

simple.  Does the error message appear?  If yes then try this

```
marque: {
    required: {
        depends: function () { return true; /* or false */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did this and nothing happened. Maybe the problem it is that this field is a drop down list. So, I used a personnal method that I used in another form. It returns an integer instead of "true" or "false" and now it's working.

Answer (score 7):

You really should be able to do this without the `depends` option, just make the function work directly on the `required` object:

```
rules: {
     marque: {
          required:  function() {
                 if (($('#add_marque').val() == "Ajouter une marque" && (('#marque').val() == -1) || ($('#add_marque').val() == "" && $('#marque').val() == -1)) {
                     return true;
                 }
                 else {
                     return false;
                 }
          }
     }
}
```

See a working, simpler example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/3hqH6/1/

Comment: Instead of the `if...else` you could simply have: `return (IF CONDITION HERE)`

Comment: I didn't want to confuse things for the asker - the problem I was solving was how to organize the `rules` object.  Good point though!

Comment: This helped resolve a similar situation in which I needed to test the specific value of another field, for which the `depends` property seemed to be appropriate. The Validator's `.call()` method on the provided function was encountering an error, but the identical function passed to `required` instead of a boolean performed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
required: {
                    depends:function (element) {
                        if ($('#inter').val() == '11' && $('#inter_rson').val() == '8') {
                            return true;
                        } else if ($('#inter').val() != '11' && $('#inter_rson').val() == '8') {
                            return true;
                        } else if ($('#inter').val() == '11' && $('#inter_rson').val() != '8') {
                            return true
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                     }
                }
```

depends works like charm when element is depends on other value as August Miller says. If you don't use depends, you may stuck at a screen with validation error.